# Complex WHERE-clause in Droidparts doesn't work

Tags: droidparts

I need complex WHERE clause.

```
final Where where1 = new Where("col_1", Is.IN, "1, 2, 3");
final Where where2 = new Where("col_2", Is.IN, "a, b, c");
final Where where = where1.and(where2);
```

but in result i got

```
SELECT on table 'table', selection: 'col_1 IN (?) AND (col_2 IN (?))',
selectionArgs: '[1, 2, 3, a, b, c]', columns: 'null', orderBy: 'null',
groupBy: 'null', having: 'null', distinct: 'false', limit: 'null'.
```

as you see all arguments are put together and result fails.

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
final Where where1 = new Where("col_1", Is.IN, 1, 2, 3);
final Where where2 = new Where("col_2", Is.IN, "a", "b", "c");
```